# Multiple integrals integration

Tags: calculus

How to evaluate the multiple integral $$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \exp(-(x^2+2xy\cos \alpha+y^2)) \, dx \, dy\text{ ?}$$ $\alpha$ is a real number and $\alpha \neq n \pi$ for any $n$.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Using polar coordinates we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty  e^{-(x^2+2\cos(\alpha)xy+y^2)}\,dx\,dy&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^\infty e^{-\rho^2(1+\cos(\alpha)\sin(2\phi))}\rho\,d\rho\,d\phi\\\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\cos(\alpha)\sin(2\phi)}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\frac12 \left|\frac{\alpha}{\sin(\alpha)}\right|
\end{align}$$

Comment: I think the last step of integration is wrong. The final answer I got is $\frac{\pi}{4 \sin\alpha}$.

Comment: @AnupamAh The result herein was obtained using the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) and validated [HERE](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2F(1%2Ba+sin(2x))+dx) by Wolframalpha.  How did you arrive at your answer?  If $\alpha \to 0$ your answer is undefined, whereas I recover correctly $1/2$.  -Mark

Comment: .I made the substitution $2\phi= \theta$ then the integral will become $\frac {1}{4} \int_0 ^ \pi \frac{1}{1+(cos \alpha) sin \theta} d\theta$. We know the value of the integral  $ \int_0 ^ \pi \frac{1}{1+asin \theta}d\theta$ is $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}$.

Comment: That is not the value of the latter integral.  Why do you believe that when for $a=1$ the integral is well behaved whereas $\pi/\sqrt{a^2-1}$ is not.